# Please help me understand finding the integral of equation

Tags: integration

I was looking through some old university booklet and found the following text:

$\frac {dC_{ol}} {dt} = k_{ol}A(C_{ol}^* - C_{ol})$

Integrating this equation gives:

$C_{ol}(t) = C_{ol}^* - (C_{ol}^* - C_{ol}(0))e^{-k_{ol}At}$

I don't understand how to obtain the 2nd equation. I'm quite new to integration, I have been reading about it but I don't know where to look for the right information to solve this one. Obviously the "$x^{n+1} / n+1$" doesn't cut it here. Can someone explain the steps in between to me and perhaps give some good references for information that can help me understand these kind of problems in the future.

I don't think this is required for the mathemetical solution, but here is some info on the parameters anyway:
$C_{ol}$ = Oxygen concentration in equilibrium with gas phase
$C_{ol}^*$ = Oxygen concentration in medium
$k_{ol}A$ = Oxygen transfer coefficient, times area A 
$t$ = time 

The equation on the top basicly gives the change in oxygen concentration per time t, which depends on some coefficient kol, the area A where the oxygen transfer is taking place, Col which is the oxygen concentration currently in the media, and Col* which is the oxygen concentration if equilibrium was reached with the gas phase (air for instance). The integrated equation gives you the amount of oxygen Col as a function of time.

Comment: I think you are looking for integration using definition i.e., Integration using limit of a sum. Try this link https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/defintdirectory/DefInt.html

Comment: But even so, where does the e suddenly come from?

Comment: $\int 1/x = \ln x$ and if you take inverse of logarithmic function then you get e. You define the exponential function as inverse function of $\ln x$ i.e., $\ln^{-1} x=e^x$